# Redirect language pages to root domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server, redirect

I have a website with two languages, native and english.

So the native looks like this: **www.example.com**,
and english version like this: **www.example.com/en**

Blog, products, and all other pages on my website have all the same domain names, either in native or in english language with only one difference - **/en subfolder**.

So all of them look like this:

www.example.com/blog **->** 
www.example.com/en/blog

www.example.com/product-123 **->** 
www.example.com/en/product-123

www.example.com/... **->** 
www.example.com/en/...

OK, so english language pages hurt my Google rankings very bad and I need to get rid of them, or exactly, redirect them to all native language domain pages themselves,

so that

www.example.com/en/blog      **is redirected to**
www.example.com/blog

www.example.com/en/product-123      **is redirected to**
www.example.com/product-123

www.example.com/en/...      **is redirected to**
www.example.com/...

**etc.**

How do i do this and where? Can it be done in htaccess?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You wrote `www.example.com/blog is redirected to www.example.com/en/blog` but title says redirect to root domain. Please clarify and also show your full .htaccess

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, working all night results this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new file `/en/.htaccess` (if not created already) and have this rule at the top:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule .* /$0 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: WOW man this worked like a charm :D i still have to test it. One more question tho if possible, do you think this could be longterm solution which wouldnt hurt SEO in the long run? Thanks

Comment: `R=301` flag in rule above will take care of SEO. I am not really a SEO expert but having duplicate content on more than one URL is usually not liked by search engines.

Comment: That is ok, i understand duplicates are not good for SEO, that is why i needed this solution, my question was referring to, if the /en pages are still seeable for google now, and will google be able reindex /en pages to the root? could you provide me more information how R=301 rule specifically is taking care of SEO? first time to hear that...   and yes, thanks you anubhava for helping ouut, this was best and fastest solution i ever had, i really appreciate it

Comment: Once search agents get `301` status for any URL then only new URL will be indexed hence `/en/....` will be dropped from search engines.